# iMovie scrolling credits alignment

Tags: imovie

My scrolling credits are aligned but when I play the movie everything is shifted.  I have changed the text size but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the layout and other attributes such as *font* and *color* in an external editor, such as **Pages**, then just copy and paste the results back into **iMovie**.  Not an ideal solution, but you get what you pay for.

See also answer to a related question: [iMovie titles line spacing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171442/imovie-titles-line-spacing)